# How select varchar size in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, types, liquibase, varchar, preconditions

There is a column in table which type is varchar, what sql select should I perform to see **defined** varchar *type* size?

**Note!**

1. The question is **not** about selecting max or min *value* in varchar column. It is need to see the defined type size.
2. Yes there is a `DESCRIBE` and `EXPLAIN` statements which can be used to see whole table definition. But this way is not sutable for me, because I need only number for liquibase precondition to detect should be column be updated or not.

Answer (score 0):

How simple it was. Just perform the following staement:

```
select CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'my_schema'
  and table_name = 'my_table'
  and column_name = 'target_column';
```